# ARMAX model with rolling window for predicting inflation

Tags: inflation, arima

First of all, similar questions like mine are answered on this forum but I never quite saw an answer to this specific question. I'm trying to predict inflation by using an AR model with exogenous variables, or ARX. I know how to figure out the order for the AR part, but it is not clear to me how to pick the exogenous variables.

first of all. Should I first build the AR model and THEN look for appropriate x variables? Or do these variables affect the AR model itself and should they be involved in picking the AR terms?
secondly, I have to use lagged exogenous variables because I want to be able to predict inflation. How do I pick the proper lags? The amount of possible models by using different variables and different lags of these variables is enormous, so just using trial and error doesn't seem the best way to go about this.
Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

TL;DR: how to figure out which features and lag to add to an ARX model?

Comment: An example of a lagged exogenous variable in this case would be something like unemployment or energy prices?  If so, it depends on which inflation is being analyzed. There are several dozen `cpie*` series in the FED database.

Comment: thanks for your comment. I use inflation as measured with the general CPI. The variables I selected to look into are for example crude oil prices, unemployment and money stock. My question is about how to properly select these (lagged) variables. How do I find out which lags to use?

Comment: Backtesting by iterating over ranges and model parameters and comparing the score. You would typically split historical data into two (or three) non-overlapping intervals, one used for training, the other for scoring. The parameters that "predicted" best the historical data can be used to predict future values.

Comment: Hi: I would start out with one lag of any exogenous variable and also not do the fitting of arima part seperately. Also, atleast initially, I would work with one exogenous variable and not pile them in all at once. Your question is good and I'm not sure there is an answer. david hendry's material might discuss this to some degree but he's got so much material, I couldn't tell you where to look.